# Moving inline styles to external css

Tags: html, css

I have a school project that requires me to not use inline style or embedded styles. I have finished the whole thing and figured that out so now I need to move stuff to my external css. I even uploaded it to my school cwp page and it isn't working as is.

Comment: Hi Jen! Using external CSS is easy, have you tried putting the styles to the separate .css file? If yes and it's not working, please, share the contents of <head></head> in your question.

Comment: I have an external css file already just not sure how to code what i want from the way i origially did it to add it to the external css.  Ill post the text in a min.  Need to get my computer.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few parts to this:

1. Firstly, create an external style sheet ('style.css' - or whatever)
2. You must reference this .css file in the head of your HTML document
3. You must accurately reference / move all inline styles to the external .css file

**Firstly, create an external style sheet ('style.css' - or whatever)**

You can do this by creating a new Notepad solution & hit 'Save As'. Ensure you save it with the extension '.css'. If you're unsure how to do this, refer here: [Save As Other File Type Notepad](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-create-a-file-without-an-extension-with-notepad)

**You must reference this .css file in the head of your HTML document**

This can be done like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Refer here for more information: [Reference External Style Sheet](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp). 


Please note, if the 'style.css' file is not in the same folder as your .html file & is instead in a folder called 'Folder', you will need to reference it like this instead:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Folder/style.css">`

**You must accurately reference / move all inline styles to the external .css file**

You can add identifiers to your tags, i.e. you can add an 'id' or a 'class' attribute to any tag, these will help reference your item in css.

You can add an id to a tag like so: 
`<label id="lblMyLabel">Example Text</label>`

 You can add a class to a tag like so: 
`<label class="lblMyLabel">Example Text</label>`


You can reference an id in css like so: `#lblMyLabel { font-weight:bold; }`

You can reference a class in css like so: `.lblMyLabel { font-weight:bold; }`


For more examples how to reference an ID see here: [CSS ID Selectors](https://www.quackit.com/css/tutorial/css_id.cfm)

For more examples how to reference a class see here: [CSS Class Selectors](https://www.quackit.com/css/tutorial/css_class.cfm)

This article gives a good overview of the conversion as well: [How To Add CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp)

**Here are examples of before & after the conversion for your reference:**

---

**BEFORE**

```html
<label style="color:green; font-weight:bold;">I am your heading</label>
```

**AFTER**

```css
#lblHeading {
      font-weight:bold;
      color:green;
    }
```

```html
<label id="lblHeading">I am your heading</label>
```

---

**BEFORE**

```html
<label style="color:green; font-weight:bold;">I am your heading</label>
```

**AFTER**

```css
.lblHeading {
          font-weight:bold;
          color:green;
        }
```

```html
<label class="lblHeading">I am your heading</label>
```

---

**BEFORE**

```html
 <div style="padding-top:10px; background-color:green;">
      <div style="padding-top:2px; background-color:red;">
          <label style="font-weight:bold;">Example</label>
          <img src="" style="height:10px;"/>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**AFTER**

```css
.outerDiv {
  padding-top:10px;
  background-color:green;
}

.outerDiv .innerDiv {
  padding-top:2px;
  background-color:red;
}

.outerDiv .innerDiv #lblMyLabel {
 font-weight:bold;
}

.outerDiv .innerDiv #imgMyImage {
 height:10px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="outerDiv">
      <div class="innerDiv">
          <label id="lblMyLabel">Example</label>
          <img id="imgMyImage" src=""/>
      </div>
    </div>
```

If you have any questions or want to supply some of your code, I'm happy to help show you a few conversions!

Answer (score 2):

Use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">` in HTML file
I put a link for tutorial to learn how to use css, I hope it will help your study
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      // Link to your external css
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>

    <body>
      <h1>This is a heading</h1>
      <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: To expand on this answer, the previously inline styles then need to be moved to `styles.css`, and that `href` value must point to where that `styles.css` file exists in the filesystem.

Comment: And ty so much!! In advance!!